# Standard Deviation of Population from Sample.

Tags: statistics, self-learning, education, statistical-inference

I guess I am a little confused. I am doing t test statistics in my class. I think I know but I would love some insight.

I am trying to get the estimated standard deviation for the population.

These are not the scores from my sample but lets uses these as examples.
$$1\ \ \ 5\ \ \ 3\ \ \ 5\ \ \ 6\ \ \ 7\ \ \ 2\ \ \ 3\ \ \ 4\ \ \ 1$$
What is my process? I have an equation for the estimated population variance is that the same thing? $\sigma^2$ is that the correct symbol? The equation is $E(x-\bar X)^2 / (n-1) = \sigma^2$ is that correct?

Comment: I appreciate the edit. I am still learning the site. I don't know if its pertinent, but the sigma square should have a hat on it to show it is an estimate. That is my understanding at least.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you're interested in the formulas for variance and standard deviation.

Being calculated over the whole population, the [variance is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition) $\sigma^2=E[(X-\mu)^2]$. This also can be writen as $\sigma^2=\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})^2$. When calculated over a sample of population this formula introduces a bias (but is still applicable as it tends to be true as the sample size tends to the population size).

The [unbiased sample variance is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance) $s^2=\frac{1}{n - 1}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\overline{x})^2$. This also can be writen as $s^2=\frac{n}{n-1}E[(X-\mu)^2]$. Now $s$ is so called [corrected sample standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation) (but not *unbiased*). The true unbiased sample standard deviation is harder to calculate because it depends on the distribution of $X$, [look here for details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Unbiased_sample_standard_deviation).

Comment: Please forgive me. My professor called the equation I wrote: E(x−X¯)^2/(n−1)=σ^2 the estimated population variance is that the same thing as the estimated population standard deviation? Or do I need to just square that answer? like the symbol shows σ^2. I don't exactly understand your equation because we don't use that formula. Maybe its just written differently. To break this down further. Is the estimated population standard deviation = to the sum of squares (for the sample) / the degrees of freedom?

Comment: Your formula does make sense if you replace $E$ with $\sum$. Because $E[X]=\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$. The relation between *variance* ($\sigma^2$) and *standard deviation* ($\sigma$) is "variance is the standard deviation **squared**".

Comment: If you prefer you can write the unbiased population variance as $\sigma^2=\frac{n}{n-1}E[(X-\mu)^2]$.

Comment: Did you mean that the standard deviation is the variance squared? Haha again I don't understand your formula it looks way more complicated than the one I listed. And the E was meant to be ∑. Anyhow thanks for trying to help. I just need to find the estimated population standard deviation i assume the professor just gave us a sample of cases since there are only 14 scores. 

A) is my equation the estimated standard deviation of a population? B) if yes why did he call it the estimation of population variance? If not why do I need to do after my equation?

Comment: Considering the word "estimated", I think your professor meant "we estimate the whole population variance from a sample of this population". So, it's sample variance (unbiased if normalized with $\frac{1}{n-1}$).

Comment: Look, variance is designated as $Var(X)=\sigma^2$. The $\sigma$ is standard deviation. So variance is standard deviation squared.

Comment: Look, I understand that σ is the sd. I also understand that the σ^2 is the formula for the estimated sample variance. My professors words: 

Q1) Use the A-4 dataset to calculate each of the following statistics for “respect for authority”: 
a) Mean of the sample 
b) Estimated standard deviation of the population 
c) Standard error of the sampling distribution 
the only numbers given which are scores from a sample dataset(I assume)
3
2.83
1
2.17
3
3.67
3.33
3.33
2.17
4
3.33
2.5
3.33
2.5

Comment: You given a sample, just calculate the "corrected sample standard deviation" to estimate the population standard deviation (see the link in the answer) for (b). Your equation is exactly what I wrote (see the last formula in the answer). In my source the $s$ is probably your $\hat{\sigma}$.

Comment: Again that doesn't help me. I appreciate it. Im sure your right. But I think that the fact Im not a math major and your not able to show me the calculation that we are not going to be able to come to a consensus. The formulas you have written and linked to just look like gibberish to me lol. Thanks for trying im just going to email the professor.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the estimated standard deviation of the population, you would simply take the sum of squares divided by degrees of freedom (n-1) and that is the estimated population variance.  In order to get the estimated SD, just take the square root of the variance.